# Is it possible to use result or state of query in same query

Tags: mysql, sql

For example I have this table events:

| user_id | event_type | date_of_event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| userA | X | 01-01-2000 |
| userA | Y | 01-01-2005 |
| userB | X | 01-01-2000 |
| userB | Y | 01-01-2100 |

I want to `select all users` that have an `event_type = X` but `no event_type Y` in the `next 2 years AFTER the date of event_type X`. So in the table above that would be userA and userB

I know I can do this in 2 mysql queries but was just wondering if there is a way to do this in just 1 query

Comment: Yes, you can do it with a self-join or with a `NOT IN` condition in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I think he means the next 2 years after the X event, not the next 2 years after now.

Comment: @Barmar updated you are correct event Y should not be 2 years after event X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a self-join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user_id
FROM yourTable AS a
LEFT JOIN yourTable AS B 
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND b.date_of_event < DATE_ADD(a.date_of_event, INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
    AND b.event_type = 'Y'
WHERE a.event_type = 'X'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.user_id
      ,t.event_type
      ,t.date_of_event

from   t join t t2 on t.user_id = t2.user_id 
         and  t.event_type <> t2.event_type
where    t.event_type = 'x'
         and          (t2.date_of_event < t.date_of_event
         or   datediff(t2.date_of_event,  t.date_of_event) > 730)
```

| user_id | event_type | date_of_event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| userA | X | 2000-01-01 |
| userB | X | 2000-01-01 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=718722a73b49b1c7549a16c0762c900d&hide=1)